# Symfony Update routes created with Loader

Tags: symfony

I have created a route Loader that creates concrete routes that points to controller. This concrete routes are based on entities so if I create or update an entity the corresponding routes needs to be created or updated. Until now the only way of doing this is using cache:clear command but I want to avoid this in production environment. I would like to just refresh the routes collection but I'm not sure if it's possible.

Comment: I suppose your could write your own command but you seems to be wanting to make code changes without running cache:clear in production?  Not a good idea.

Comment: I have used  ($this->get('cache_warmer')->warmUp($this->getParameter('kernel.cache_dir'));) but it only refresh the UrlGenerator and UrlMatcher sometimes and I'm not sure about why only sometimes.

Comment: Finally I'm clearing cache completely as I haven't found a more reliable method.